# Is there a template to create a project of directories and files?

Tags: elisp

Is there a template to create a group of directories and files for a new project?

Example:

- List of predefined directories:  `(.c .c_b .o .o_b .docs .invoices)`
- List of predefined blank files:  `(1add.txt .../invoices/costs.txt)`

`M-x template-setup`

`(read-string "Please select your project root directory:  " default-directory)`

- If file or directory already exists, then skip and keep on going creating the remainder.

Comment: I believe http://cedet.sourceforge.net/srecode.shtml is the tool used by EDE, but it may be a bit too much, if you are just looking for something simple.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. But (with [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) you can bookmark any set of files and directories. And the bookmark can use Dired, thus recording markings, omission set, and subdir inclusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package [skeletor](https://github.com/chrisbarrett/skeletor.el) allows one to create projects based on predefined templates. It also allows you to define custom project templates. You might want to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

**Initial Draft** (December 25, 2014):  The following is a revised initial draft.  It incorporates a lesson learned from @tarsius as to using a let-bound `default-directory` with `start-process` ( https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5739/2287 ) [i.e., it *must* have a trailing forward slash]; and, a lesson learned from @legoscia regarding using `lexical-let` to penetrate the `set-process-sentinel` hierarchy with a temporary variable value ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/24549625/2112489 ); and, a prior discovery of mine regarding using `recursive-edit` to temporarily hold off going through the remainder of a function until the sub-processes have finished ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237869/fine-tuning-set-process-sentinel-set-process-filter-start-process ).

**EDIT** (December 29, 2014):  Removed `default-directory` from `lexical-let` and also from the let-bound wrap around of the `start-process` statement -- said code was not needed.  `recursive-edit` is now a part of the `mapcar` section of code relating to file creation -- exiting occurs each time a new file has been created.

```
(let* (
    (proposed-directories '(
      "0.pdd_fdd" "0.oah" "0.c" "0.c_b" "0.o" "0.o_b" "0.f" "0.discovery"
      "0.docs" "0.deeds" "0.pleadings" "0.invoices"))
    (proposed-filenames '("1add.txt" "0.invoices/bill.txt"))
    (default-directory (file-name-as-directory ;; ensure there is a trailing forward slash
      (read-string "Set the temporary default directory: " default-directory))) )
  (mapcar
    (lambda (x) (make-directory x t))
    proposed-directories)
  (mapcar
    (lambda (x)
      (lexical-let ((x x))
        (set-process-sentinel
          (start-process "touch-file" nil "touch" x)
          (lambda (p e)
            (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
              (message "Created:  %s" x)
              (throw 'exit nil)))))
      (recursive-edit))
       proposed-filenames)
  (when (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
    (revert-buffer)))
```