# Temporarily set the `default-directory` for `start-process`

Tags: process, subprocess

Is it possible to set the `default-directory` temporarily (e.g., let-bound) when using `start-process`?  If so, how please.

```
(let ((default-directory "/Users/HOME/Desktop/tmp"))
  (start-process "touch-file" nil "touch" "test.txt"))
```

`start-process` ignores a let-bound `default-directory`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`default-directory` has to be a directory, not the filename of a directory. In other words it has to end with a slash. In some places it does not matter whether a directory path ends with a slash or not, here it does.

```
(let ((default-directory "/some/directory/"))
  ...)
```

Comment: Works on linux without a slash

Comment: I'm on OSX, so in my case it made the difference -- i.e., `expand-file-name` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

Just expand the file name:

```
(let ((default-directory "/Users/HOME/Desktop/tmp"))
  (start-process "touch-file" nil "touch"
                 (expand-file-name "test.txt")))
```

Comment: tarsius hit the nail on the head, so I had to move the checkmark -- sorry -- your help is always appreciated.  A forward slash at the end of the `default-directory` eliminates the need for `expand-file-name` on an OSX machine.